# Why does field splitting not occur after parameter expansion in an assignment statement in shell?

Tags: shell, posix, variable-assignment

Consider the following two assignments.

```
$ a="foo  bar"
$ b=$a
$ b=foo  bar
bash: bar: command not found
```

Why does the second assignment work fine? How is the second command any different from the third command?

I was hoping the second assignment to fail because

```
b=$a
```

would expand to

```
b=foo  bar
```

Since `$a` is not within double-quotes, `foo  bar` is not quoted, therefore field-splitting should occur (as per my understanding) which would result in `b=foo` to be considered an assignment and `bar` to be a command that cannot be found.

Summary: I was expecting the 2nd command to fail for the same reason that caused the 3rd command to fail. Why does the 2nd command succeed?

I went through the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) but I am unable to find anything that specifies that field splitting won't occur after parameter expansion that occurs in an assignment.

I mean anywhere else field splitting would occur for an unquoted parameter after parameter expansion. For example,

```
$ a="foo  bar"
$ printf "[%s] [%s]\n" $a
[foo] [bar]
```

See [Section 2.6.5](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).

> After parameter expansion (Parameter Expansion), command substitution (Command Substitution), and arithmetic expansion (Arithmetic Expansion), the shell shall scan the results of expansions and substitutions that did not occur in double-quotes for field splitting and multiple fields can result.

So which part of the POSIX standard prevents field splitting when parameter expansion occurs in an assignment statement?

Comment: Why would you "hope for" that behavior? It would make the language that much more difficult to use correctly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't hope for that behavior. I am trying to understand how the current behaviour is specified by the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) standard. Although I am not quite sure why you believe the other behaviour (field-splitting after parameter expansion in assignment) would make the language more difficult to use. We are already used to quoting parameter expansions, e.g. `ls "$foo"`. It is not especially much more difficult to do so in assignments too, e.g. `b="$a"`.

Comment: BTW, while there've been several revisions, I presently consider my answer complete.

Comment: The idea is that splitting and globbing only happen in contexts that expect multiple words. The right-hand side of an assignment is a single word so no splitting happens. What constitutes a single-word context can be subtle, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary if you want a detailed overview.

Comment: A favorite:  [Command line psychology 101](http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-02-1998/swol-02-unix101.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.9.1, "Simple Commands":

> The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to Shell Grammar Rules are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.

Step 2 -- which is explicitly skipped in this case per the above text -- reiterates that it ignores assignments when performing expansion and field splitting:

> The words that are **not variable assignments or redirections** shall be expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the first field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are the arguments for the command.

Thus, it's step 2 that determines the command to run (based on contents other than variable assignments and redirections), which addresses the `b=$a` case given in your question.

---

Step 4 performs other expansions -- "tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal" -- for assignments. Notably, field splitting is not a member of this set. Indeed, it's explicit in 2.6 that none of these create multiple words in and of themselves:

> Tilde expansions, parameter expansions, command substitutions, arithmetic expansions, and quote removals that occur within a single word expand to a single field. **It is only field splitting or pathname expansion that can create multiple fields from a single word.** The single exception to this rule is the expansion of the special parameter '@' within double-quotes, as described in Special Parameters.

Comment: What really is a word in case of `a=$b`? Is the entire `a=$b` considered one word? Or is `a` a word and `$b` another word?

Comment: This is why you can't have spaces around `=`, because it **must** be a single word.

Comment: I don't think the last quote (`It is only field splitting or pathname expansion that can create multiple fields from a single word`) is relevant for this question. For example, in `ls $a`, the `$a` may create multiple fields because `$a` is not quoted, so field splitting would occur after `$a` is expanded. So one would expect that despite what you have quoted in the end, field splitting may occur for `a=$b` too. That's why I believe that the last quote is not relevant. But the other sections you quoted are relevant but none of them explicitliy forbids field splitting for assignment.